# DX standard pick-list values in unlocked package

Tags: salesforcedx, picklist, unlocked-package, standard-field

We have certain parts of our org metadata that we can't put in an unlocked package because they are dependent on standard pick-list values (i.e. opportunity stage).

Is there a way to put standard pick-list values into a unlocked package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. Some metadata like picklist values for standard fields are not packagable.

I recommend if metadata API exists keeping them in a separate metadata folder with proper package.xml manifest will ease deployments.

Comment: thank you for the information.  That is a good solution to this.